# regex to remove first letter if it's k and everything after the last underscore (including the underscore)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this RegEx that i need to polish that if the first letter of the string is k then remove it and remove everything after the last underscore.

```
(?<=a)[\w\-=~ ]+(?=_) or 
(^.*?(?=k)k)|[_].*$ or
^K|(.*_).*
```

This works if string is:

kMy new file (conn) - vital_esxi.dsss

output: My new file (conn) - vital

but fails for following string:

input:   aeeff adlf (adf) - region_ev akjd _pre.docx

output should be: aeeff adlf (adf) - region_ev akjd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression could be way simpler:

```
const regex = /^k?(.*?)\_[^_]*$/;

console.log('aeeff adlf (adf) - region_ev akjd _pre.docx'.replace(regex, '$1'));
console.log('kMy new file (conn) - vital_esxi.dsss'.replace(regex, '$1'));
```